# Java Generics : How to avoid casting in this example of java 2D generic arrays?

Tags: java, generics

I'm modeling a board, I wanted to make it as generic as I can,I also wanna avoid casting at all cost, because it's a bad practice!

Also, My code is completely working as right now, but I know as soon as I start working with Cell class and extend it, it'll be problematic!

Cell.java

```
public class Cell<T> {
    private t value;

    public Cell(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

Board.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public abstract class Board<T, E extends Cell<T>> {
    protected E[][] cells;

    protected Board(Class<? extends E> c) {
        cells = (E[][])Array.newInstance(c, 6, 7);
    }

    protected void resetBoard(T resteVal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                cells[i][j]= (E) new Cell<T>(); //HERE IS THE QUESTION
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
public interface Game {
    boolean islegalMove();
    boolean isWin();
    void move();
    void resetGame();
    void getScore();
}
```

Connect4.java

```
public class Connect4<E extends Cell<Integer>> extends Board<Integer,E> implements Game {
    public Connect4(Class<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    // override methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this `protected E[][] cells;` by `protected Cell<T>[][] cells;`

```
public abstract class Board<T, E extends Cell<T>> {
    protected Cell<T>[][] cells;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Board(Class<? extends E> c) {
        cells = (E[][])Array.newInstance(c, 6, 7);
    }

    protected void resetBoard(T resteVal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
                Cell<T> cell =  new Cell<T>();
                cell.setValue(resteVal);
                cells[i][j] = cell; //HERE IS MY REPLACEMENT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The core proble is not correct architecture (class casting says exactly about it). This is not correct fix of this problem.

Comment: What, I didn't get it?

Comment: the problem is, in this case you do not have access to the classes that extending Cell class, and this make the whole point of having E meaningless!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in architecture.

You have define `Cell<T>` class (e.g. it could be extendable).

Then you define an abstract `Board`, that could work with custom `Cell`.

```
public abstract class Board<T, E extends Cell<T>> {
    // why do not use T[][] cells instead?
    protected final E[][] cells;

    protected Board(E[][] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    // we hole Cell instances inside this class, so no need to create new ones
    protected void resetBoard(T resetVal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                cells[i][j].setValue(resetVal);
    }
}
```

And finally, we could defeine an **concrete board** with concrete **cell instance**.

```
public final class MagicBoard<T> extends Board<T, MagicBoard.MagicCell<T>> {

    public MagicBoard(Supplier<MagicCell<T>> supplier) {
        //noinspection rawtypes,unchecked
        super(new MagicCell[6][7]);
    }

    public static final class MagicCell<T> extends Cell<T> { }
}
```

Resume:

1. Abstract class `Board` should not ware about concrete cell instance creating. Maximum, it could accept `Supplier` from child class to delegate this work to concrete class 'MagicBoard' (only this class knows what type of `Cell` should be created).
2. Try to avoid useless `Cell` instance creating. If you hold it inside `Board` and do not share it outside it, then reuse it. Just reset the value.
3. **Question!** I do not know whole code, but if your `Cell` contains only one value, you could avoid using `Cell` and use `protected final T[][] cells;` instead (I think, that `Board` should contains all logic for working with `Cell`, but cells itself should not be very clever - just keep simple value). But this is only my opinion.

Comment: mentioned cell class is just an example,many classes will using it and they have their attributes and methods,so i think it's necessary to have it in my code! the reason that I didn't T cells is I can easily extend Cell class and manipulate my board with new cells,take a look at Connect4 class!